# How to improve .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following structure on my apache root folder:

System -> Folder with all php files of my system.

WebService - > Folder with php files for webservice.

Crontab -> Folder with crontab routines.

Error.php -> php file to manage errors (404,403,500) .

This is my htacess inside my system folder, is there any way of improving it?

```
 # Blocks the folder listing
 Options -Indexes

 # url configuration
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

# Search system
RewriteRule ^Busca(/.*)?$ Search/$1.php

# Forces the use of https
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/$1 [R,L]

# Removes the final dash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://127.0.0.1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolves .php to external domains
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Blocks .php on URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://127.0.0.1/erro?n=403 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
# Protects the .htaccess file
 <files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</files>

# Forces the use of UTF-8
<FilesMatch ".(htm|html|php|css|js)$">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</FilesMatch>

# Basic compression
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|php|js)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

 # Protects the files and directories
 <FilesMatch "(\.(Search|CSS|Funcoes|Imagens|Paginas|JS|Modules|Fonts|.*sql|Instalacao|WebServer|Arquivos|Crontab(\.php)? |xtmpl)|code-style\.pl)$">
Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: What are you trying to improve? The HTML boilerplate does a pretty good job of best practices for htaccess https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess   Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, the improvements can be countless.... but that does not mean they're necessary... as @IsabelInc has said. What is it you want to improve? Security?